# Handling Form in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, forms, next.js

In this code example I would like to try to do easy math (ket=name + names). The sum should be a number and displayed as “ket”. But when I type in 3 and 6 in my input fields, “ket” shows up to be 36 (and not 9).

```js
export default function Kettenl() {
  const submitContact = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const names = event.target.names.value;
    const name = event.target.name.value;
    let ket = name + names;
    alert(`So your name is ${ket}?`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-xs my-2 overflow-hidden rounded shadow-lg">
      <div className="px-6 py-4">
        <div className="mb-2 text-xl font-bold">Contact us</div>
        <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={submitContact}>
          <label htmlFor="name" className="mb-2 italic">
            Name
          </label>
          <input
            className="mb-4 border-b-2"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            type="number"
            required
          />
          <label htmlFor="name" className="mb-2 italic">
            Names
          </label>
          <input
            className="mb-4 border-b-2"
            id="names"
            name="names"
            type="number"
            required
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white bg-blue-500 rounded-full hover:bg-blue-700"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the values are being read as strings
'3'+'6'='36'
you should change it to this

```
const names = parseInt(event.target.names.value);
const name = parseInt(event.target.name.value);
```

Also, you are storing and accessing the values incorrectly. You should learn the basics of react before moving on to next.js.
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
Read about controlled and uncontrolled inputs from the docs
So even if your app works with the aforementioned change, you shouldn't be doing it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because values are returned as a string by default from your target element. For inputs with `type="number"` you can just use the input value with `e.target.names.valueAsNumber`.

```js
const submitContact = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const names = event.target.names.valueAsNumber;
    const name = event.target.name.valueAsNumber;
    let ket = name + names;
    alert(`So your name is ${ket}?`);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it's sufficient to define my input as "number"..